# Rails form helpers errors html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

When I create a form with form helpers and put it in invalid data, the fields that get added by the error tags get put all between quotes and a see in the html the following:

```
"<span class="fieldWithErrors"><label for="email">Email</label></span> <span class="fieldWithErrors"><input id="email" name="email" size="30" type="text" value="adfasd" /></span>"
```

Note the quotes around the whole text which means this is the actual text when browsing from a website.

The messages on top appear to be correct but for some reason, it adds these quotes around it all. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you show your .erb_file

Comment: Solved the issue. I had forgotten the .html_safe at end of tag in 
    ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| %(<span class="fieldWithErrors">#{html_tag}</span>).html_safe }
Thanks though